# Trouble with Air Traffic Control Program using LinkedList Java

Tags: java, linked-list, implementation

I've been working on this program for a few weeks now, it's our final project in my Java programming class and it has been giving me (and a lot of other students) some pretty good headaches. 
We need to create a program that allows a user to enter, display and remove new planes along with the plane's speed, altitude and type of plane. 
I've been having the most problems with getting the main class to communicate with the other classes. Because of this, I don't know if my LinkedList is going to work properly, or if at all. I'm worried that the list is not going to properly store all the fields together and that the node is not properly coded.
I could really use any help or advice you can provide. Code is below. I'm open to any and all suggestions. The code does not have to stay in exactly the same classes it is currently in. If something would work better somewhere else, I'd be happy to try it.

Main Class. This is where the user will be interacting with the program. I have been having a hard time getting the methods from other classes to work in this class. I'm sure it is something simple that I am missing.

```
package airTraffic;

import java.util.*;

public class Main {

static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    do {
        try {
            System.out.println("Please enter command to proceed: ");
            System.out.println("Enter new aircraft = e");
            System.out.println("Display all aircraft = d");
            System.out.println("Show specific flight = s");
            System.out.println("Remove specific flight = r");
            String command = in.next();
            in.next(command);

            if ( (in.next(command)).equals("e") ) {
                ATControl.addToList();  // need to somehow "start" this class 

            } else if ( (in.next(command)).equals("d") ) {
                ATControl.displayAll();

            } else if ( (in.next(command)).equals("s") ){
                ATControl.showFlight();

            } else if ( (in.next(command)).equals("r") ) {
                ATControl.removeFlight();

            } else if ( (in.next(command)).equals(null) ) {
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException exc) {
            System.out.println("Wrong entry, please try again:");
        }
    } while (true);
}
}
```

Linked List and Node - I called it Aircraft. I think this is where the list is stored and created. Manipulation to the list occurs in the next class (ATControl), or at least I think it will.

```
package airTraffic;

import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Aircraft  {

// stores data
private static final int INITIAL_ALLOCATION = 20;
private int size = INITIAL_ALLOCATION; 

//declare LinkedList and node names
static LinkedList <String> list = new LinkedList <String> ();
private Aircraft head = new Aircraft ();
private Aircraft tail = new Aircraft ();

// tells list to add nodes
public  void addNodes (int n, LinkedList<String> s) {
    s = list;
    head.next = tail;
    tail.next = tail;
    size = n;
    Aircraft temp = head;
    for (int i= 0; i < size; ++i) {
        temp.next = new Aircraft ();
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    temp.next = tail;
}

private String value;
Aircraft craft;

public Aircraft (String v) {
    value = v;
}

public Aircraft () {

}

public String get () {
    return value;
}

public void set (String v) {
    value = v;
}

public Aircraft next = null;

//auto generated method from ATControl 
public static void add(String flight) {
    // a for or while loop might be needed here. Seems to easy to just have an empty add class

}
//auto generated method from ATControl
public static void remove() {

}
 }
```

ATControl class. This is where (I think) the list is manipulated, allowing the user to add, remove and show the flights.

```
package airTraffic;

import java.util.*;

public class ATControl{

// implement Aircraft class (node) - empty argument list?? 
Aircraft aircraft = new Aircraft ();

static Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

// list of planes 
static String [] planeList = {"Wide-body Airliner = w", "Regional Airliner = r", "Private Plane = p", 
        "Military = m", "Cargo only: c", "Unknown = u"};

//add plane and details
public static void addToList () {
    System.out.printf("Enter flight number: ");
    String flight = in.nextLine();
    Aircraft.add(flight);

    //type of plane
    System.out.printf("Enter type of plane, ", "Choose from: " + planeList);
    String type = in.nextLine();
    try {
    if (type == "w") {
         System.out.println("Wide-body Airliner");
    }else if (type == "r") {
             System.out.println("Regional Airliner");
    }else if (type == "p") {
         System.out.println("Private Plane");
    }else if (type == "m") {
         System.out.println("Military");
    }else if (type == "c") {
         System.out.println("Cargo only");
    }else if (type == "u") {
         System.out.println("Unknown");
    } else type = null;
        }
    catch (InputMismatchException i) {
        System.out.println("You must enter valid command: " + planeList);
    }
    Aircraft.add(type);

    //plane speed
    System.out.printf("Enter current speed: ");
    String speed = in.nextLine();
    Aircraft.add(speed);

    //add Altitude 
    System.out.printf("Enter current altitude: ");
    String alt = in.nextLine();
    Aircraft.add(alt);
}

//show flight
public static void showFlight () {
    System.out.printf("Enter flight number for details: ");
    in.nextLine();
    Aircraft.get(Aircraft, index);
}

// display all flights
public static void displayAll () {
    System.out.printf("All flights: " );

}

//remove flight
public static void removeFlight () {
    System.out.printf("Enter flight number to be removed: ");
    in.nextLine();
    Aircraft.remove();
}   
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: First piece of advice is to unit test the separate pieces.  Work with your LinkedList by itself until you're comfortable that it is solid, working code before you try to bring everything together at once.  Devise some complex scenario of adding, removing, etc. a bunch of flights and then check the list is still correct.

Comment: ATControl should be static to use it in such way on your main

Comment: i'll give you general tips... 1) use ArrayList 2) plane types could be an enum 3) don't use two scanners that read System.in 4) that String you made from in.next() - use it instead of invoking dozens of in.next() calls... your program will block on each of them, expecting input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using object oriented design, think of your objects as representations of actual objects. Your aircraft class should represent an actual aircraft. The aircraft should keep track of things that are associated with it. So things like flight number, speed, altitude, etc.. should be properties of that class.

```
public class Aircraft{
    private int speed;
    private int altitude;
    private int flightNum;
    //
    //Regional Airliner, Military, Private Plane, etc.
    private String type;

    public void setSpeed(int speed){
        this.speed = speed;
    }
    public int getSpeed(){
        return speed;
    }
    //
    //TODO: Getters and Setters for the rest of the aircraft properties

}
```

Now pretty much everything else should be handled by your ATControl class. An array list of type Aircraft seems much more logical to use in this case.

```
public class ATControl{
    private ArrayList<Aircraft> currentFlights;

    //
    //Constructor gets called on initialization
    public ATControl(){
        currentFlights = new ArrayList<Aircraft>();
    }

    //
    //User input should be handled in main class and passed into this
    public void addFlight(int flightNum, int speed, int altitude){
        Aircraft newCraft = new Aircraft();

        //
        //assign the properties we just got from the user to our new aircraft
        newCraft.setFlightNumber(flightNum);
        newCraft.setSpeed(speed);
        //
        //Now add our new flight to the list of current flights
        currentFlights.add(newCraft);

    }


}
```

Your main class can remain pretty much as you have it. I would handle all user input there, though.

```
public class Main {

    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


    public static void main(String[] args) {
       ATControl denverTrafficControl = new ATControl();
       //
       //Handle user input here: get the speed, altitude, flightNum, etc..

       denverTrafficControl.addFlight(flightNum, speed, altitude);

    }
}
```

This is how it should be done. Hopefully this has helped you grasp the objected oriented design a bit better. Let the main class handle I/O and your other actual "object" classes handle the data. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this does make more sense to me now. I wish we could use something as simple as an Array List or a Linked List, but part of the assignment is to create our own Linked List using Nodes. I had a Linked List originally, but professor told me to get rid of it. 
He tends to make our homework more complicated than it needs to be

Answer (score 2):

To "start" ATControl, you need to create a new instance of it:

```
ATControl control = new ATControl();
control.addToList();
```

Same with your `Aircraft`. You will want to create new instances with `new`, and then call `Add()`, etc. on them.

You will also probably want to pass your `Scanner` from main into the new ATControl and use it to read the input, instead of using a brand new `Scanner`

Comment: Thank you for the advice - it has been helpful thus far. One thing does have me a bit lost though, how would I go about passing the Scanner from Main to ATControl? I see what you are saying, but coding it is a different story. Thanks again!

Comment: You should change the function insite ATControl:
public static void addToList (Scanner in){
    ...
    in.nextLine();
    ...
}

and inside your main call it as follows:
control.addToList(in);

Answer (score 0):

- Your general design seems to ignore object oriented principles. As I see it, aircraft should hold its type, speed and altitude together in one object.
- Why reinvent the wheel? There are plenty of premade (and well tested) collection classes already built into the JRE (e.g. ArrayList, LinkedList). Make use of them to hold your aircraft instances.

These two changes should drastically reduce the amount of code you need to write/maintain and the overall complexity of the program should be reduced considerably.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, if it ignores OOP principles, it is because I am new to this and honestly really don't know what I am doing.
When you say "aircraft should hold its type" - what exactly do you mean? One of the things I am having trouble with is figuring out how to hold everything together in one object. Our text book doesn't give very detailed examples of a complex example like our current project. 
Thank again for the feedback